# Clearing a SIM Card

Tags: 2.2-froyo, settings, sim-card

After doing a factory reset on my phone, I reinserted the SIM card into the phone and I got a message suggesting that I import settings, messages, and contacts from my SIM card to my phone.

I know how to delete messages and contacts on the SIM card after importing them to the phone.  My question is, how do I delete the settings from the SIM card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Subscriber Identity Module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module) commonly known as SIM card has a storage for text (SMS) messages and contacts only.  Settings (I presume you are talking about access points and GPRS/3G configuration - clarify it you mean something else) about your phone are not stored, except the carrier related parameters like message service center number, value added services codes etc.